# Response to MediaBttuon not working when Trying to play sound over BluetoothSco

Tags: android

I have implemented  handling MediaButton event according to developers guide Both in UI Activity and Active Media Session. When I try to play sound over bluetoothSco it starts to miss MediaButton events. this are the lines of  code I added to play sound over BluetoothSCO

AudioManager localAudioManager;
            localAudioManager = (AudioManager) CallFrameGUIActivity.this.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();

Answer (score 0):

Because you use mode_in_communication.

```
localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)
```